# Images disappear when on certain mobile devices

Tags: html, image, css

So I've recently completed my website and have seen that the two images on my home don't show up on certain mobile devices. I'm not to sure why. In any case here the code is below. You can also see the live view of my website [here](http://kadeem.london). Just to reiterate it works fine on desktop, however on certain mobile devices the images simply disappear, or seem to be hiding behind the get in touch section. I thank you in advance for any help.

```css
 .My-Gems {
     width: 100%;
 }


@media screen and (max-width:444px) {  
 .My-Gems {
     width: 100%;
     margin-top:-370px;
    }}

    @media screen and (max-width:333px) {  
 .My-Gems {
     width: 100%;
     margin-top:-380px;
    }}


  .Second-Header {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 5em;
     margin-top:4em;
     position: relative;
     color:#fff;
 }

 @media (max-width: 777px){
    .Second-Header {
     margin-bottom: 4em;
     margin-top:3em;
}
}


 @media (max-width: 666px){
    .Second-Header {
     margin-bottom: 3em;
     margin-top:2em;
}
}

 @media (max-width: 555px){
    .Second-Header {
     margin-bottom: 2em;
     margin-top:1em;
}
}

 @media (max-width: 555px){
    .Second-Header {
     margin-top:.5em;
}
}
  .Second-Header h2 {
     font-family:'Abril Fatface', cursive;
     font-size:2.5em;
     font-weight: 400;
     color:fff;
 }


@media (max-width: 777px){
    .Second-Header h2{
        font-size:2em;
}
}

@media (max-width: 666px){
    .Second-Header h2{
        font-size:1.8em;
}
}

@media (max-width: 555px){
    .Second-Header h2{
        font-size:1.5em;
}
}

@media (max-width: 444px){
    .Second-Header h2{
        font-size:1.3em;
}
}

@media (max-width: 333px){
    .Second-Header h2{
        font-size:1.2em;
}
}

@media (max-width: 222px){
    .Second-Header h2{
        font-size:1em;
}
}


 .item {
     text-align:center;
              -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

         -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
         transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     float:left;
     position:relative;
 }
 .item {
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
 }
 .item-hover, .item-hover .mask, .item-img, .item-info {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
 .item-hover, .item-hover .mask {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     height:100%;
     left:0;
 }
 .item-type-double .item-hover {
     z-index:5;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     opacity:0;
     cursor:pointer;
     display:block;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-align:center;
 }
 .item-type-double .item-info {
     z-index:10;
     color:#ffffff;
     display:table;
     position:relative;
     z-index:5;
 }
 .item-type-double .item-info div.mycell {
     vertical-align:middle;
     height: 100%;
     display:table-cell;
 }
 .item-type-double .item-info .headline {
     font-size:2.4em;    
     font-family: 'Proxima Nova' sans-serif;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     width:90%;
     margin:0 auto;
 }
 @media (max-width: 888px) {
     .item-type-double .item-info .headline {
         font-size:1.8em;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         width:90%;
         margin:0 auto;
     }
 }
 @media (max-width: 666px) {
     .item-type-double .item-info .headline {
         font-size:1.4em;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         width:90%;
         margin:0 auto;
     }
 }
 @media (max-width: 444px) {
     .item-type-double .item-info .headline {
         font-size:1.3em;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         width:90%;
         margin:0 auto;
     }
 }
 @media (max-width: 390px) {
     .item-type-double .item-info .headline {
         font-size:0.8em;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         width:90%;
         margin:0 auto;
     }
 }

  @media (max-width: 333px) {
     .item-type-double .item-info .headline {
         font-size:0.6em;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         width:90%;
         margin:0 auto;
     }
 }

   @media (max-width: 222px) {
     .item-type-double .item-info .headline {
         font-size:0.5em;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         width:90%;
         margin:0 auto;
     }
 }
 .item-type-double .item-info .date {
     font-size:20px;
     font-family:'Canter';
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
@media (max-width:444px){
    .item-type-double .item-info .date {
     font-size:16px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 } 
}

@media (max-width:333px){
    .item-type-double .item-info .date {
     font-size:10px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 } 
}



 .item-type-double .item-hover .mask {
     background-color:#000;
     -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
     /*filter: alpha(opacity=50);*/
     opacity:0.5;
     z-index:0;
 }
 .item-type-double .item-hover:hover .line {
     width:90%;
 }
 .item-type-double .item-hover:hover {
     opacity:1;
 }
 .item-img {
     width:100%;
     z-index:0;
 }
 .item-img img {
     width:100%;
     display:block
 }
```

```html
<div class="My-Gems">
<div class="Second-Header"><h2></h2></div>
<div class="item item-type-double">
<div class="item-img">

<img src="http://kadeem.london/Image/Money-Matters-Logo.png" class="menukadeem" title="Money-Matters-Logo" alt="Money-Matters-Logo"/>
</div>
<a class="item-hover" href="designs.html">
<div class="item-info">
<div class="mycell">
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="headline">Designs</div>
<div class="line"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mask"></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="item item-type-double">
<div class="item-img">
<img src="http://kadeem.london/Image/Metaphon-Fitness.jpg" alt="Metaphon-Fitness" title="Metaphon-Fitness" style="width:100%;"/>
</div>
<a class="item-hover" href="events.html">
<div class="item-info">
<div class="mycell">
<!--<div class="date">Events</div>-->
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="headline">Events</div>
<div class="line"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="mask"></div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Testing the above snippet in FF, both images disappear when I resize below 444px.  That's a clue I think...

Comment: OMG!!!! I have never ever seen that many media queries!!!! Why so many?!?!?!

Comment: Yes I went a bit overboard with the media queries. Just recently started using them. Thanks @wwwmarty I'll have a look at that now.

Comment: Nope, I've amended the code.The image still disappears, left remaining the width of the divs.

Comment: In two places you move things to hide almost a vertical screen full of information,  eg `margin-top:-370px`; -  this may be the problem since it happens for screens under 400px in size. Also are setting the viewport in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: just checked this with screenfly from quirktools - which tests different screensizes -  images show even on the smallest around 260px wide. Could this be a browser compatibility issue? 

Oddly I can't see the .mask class in your code and it appears to be applied to any empty `<div>`?,

Comment: Ok sure, thanks for the help guys, it's quite odd still looking into it though.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it is the device. I have tested it on [MobileTest](http://mobiletest.me/)

On none of the devices do the images disappear. If you have certain phones in which you believe cause the problem, as well as the browser you use in order to test the website, please comment them, otherwise it is most likely the phone itself.